# OpenCV3 image.depth() is zero

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I tried to follow [this OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-efficient-way) about loading and modifying an image. I load the image like this:

```
I = imread( filename, IMREAD_COLOR );
```

Later in the code there is a `CV_Assert`:

```
CV_Assert(I.depth() != sizeof(uchar));
```

It is not true, because `I.depth()` is zero and `sizeof(uchar)` is one.

What do I wrong? If I call `imshow`, then the image is displayed correctly

Comment: This is correct in the [last doc](https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html) with `CV_Assert(I.depth() == CV_8U);`. Forget about the OpenCV version 3.0-beta, it's buggy and bad documented ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`I.depth()` doesn't return size of elements. It returns one of [depth defines](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/a6c02af0991fd359cf4501e02acf5f3f9d4ae91d/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/hal/interface.h#L67):

```
#define CV_8U   0
#define CV_8S   1
#define CV_16U  2
#define CV_16S  3
#define CV_32S  4
#define CV_32F  5
#define CV_64F  6
```

If you want get size of element, you can use `I.elemSize1()`